Highest quarterly (or other indexed) sum for items in Excel
I have a table in Excel with Quarter, City, Item, and Sales:



Quarter
City
Item
Sales




2023-Q1
Smallville
Reticulated Spline
15


2023-Q1
Smallville
Red Llama
13


2023-Q1
Townsburg
Reticulated Spline
35


2023-Q1
Townsburg
Red Llama
27


2023-Q2
Smallville
Reticulated Spline
7


2023-Q2
Smallville
Red Llama
11


2023-Q2
Townsburg
Reticulated Spline
39


2023-Q2
Townsburg
Red Llama
37



The real table has 10 cities, 20 items, and currently data for 18 quarters, but this should give you the idea.
I want, for each Item, to find the best total quarterly sales, e.g.



Item
Best Quarterly Total Sales




Reticulated Spline
50


Red Llama
48



The best Quarter for the Reticulated Spline was 2023-Q1, and for the Red Llama was 2023-Q2, but I don't need to know that.
How can I achieve this in Excel? I have tried creating a pivot table, but I have not been able to find a solution.
The long-term goal is for a different sheet, a template where you enter current figures, to compare those figures with the quarterly best for each Item, and for each Item show by how much the quarterly best was increased (0 if less than quarterly all-time-high for that Item).
I inherited the Excel-sheet, which was quite poorly built, so I am free to redo it if some other way to organize the data is better suited.

Here is one way of doing this using Excel Formulas this assuming as per the tags there is no Excel Constraints as well:


• Formula used in cell F2
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D13,
     _QtrIt, INDEX(_Data,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Data,,3),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_QtrIt),
     _Item, TEXTAFTER(_Uniq,"|"),
     _Sorted, SORT(HSTACK(_Item, 
     MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_QtrIt)),TAKE(_Data,,-1))),2,-1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Item,VLOOKUP(_Item,_Sorted,2,0))))


If you like using LAMBDA() helper functions then using BYROW()
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D13,
     _QtrIt, INDEX(_Data,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Data,,3),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_QtrIt),
     _Item, TEXTAFTER(_Uniq,"|"),
     _Sorted, SORT(HSTACK(_Item,
     BYROW(_Uniq,LAMBDA(x,SUM((x=_QtrIt)*TAKE(_Data,,-1))))),2,-1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Item,VLOOKUP(_Item,_Sorted,2,0))))


BTW if you have access to GROUPBY() function, which is presently in Office Insiders could try the following as well:
=LET(
     _Data, SORT(DROP(GROUPBY(HSTACK(A2:A13,C2:C13),D2:D13,SUM,,0),,1),2,-1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(C2:C13),
     HSTACK(_Uniq,VLOOKUP(_Uniq,_Data,2,0)))



Just wow! Took some time to translate all formulas to local Excel language, but this works just so great!

@LapplandsCohan, i have approved it but, TAKE() is a new function in MS365 also INDEX() works here as well. You can read here Glad to know it worked

With Pivot Table
Add a calculated item to the columns as in the screenshot.


As more data gets added, is there some way to make this include all data so I don't have to update the max formula each quarter?

AFAIK this can be done only with VBA.
